# Do you have to run Remote Desktop to access Terminal Services?

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server

One of our clients want to run MYOB (an accounting desktop application) over Terminal Services (that's what's recommended by MYOB themselves for multi-user access).

I have no previous experience with TS and have the (probably stupid) following question:

Given a Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition, properly setup for terminal services, and the MYOB application installed on that server, are Windows clients required to open a Remote Desktop session to access the application? Ie., is there a way to launch the application so that it feels "integrated" with the operating system? Maybe something similar to what VMware Unity does?

I would just like to avoid that the client be confused by having two desktops, etc.

Comment: Hey, there aren't stupid questions. I clicked on this one because I didn't know the answer either. Thanks for asking it!

Comment: "I would just like to avoid that the client be confused by having two desktops"

TS remote applications are very nice.  I like that I can just distribute the file in a .msi to end users and they enjoy the "integrated" feeling of running it on their local machines.

Your next step is configuring TS-Gateway so they users can do the same thing from home :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no need for the client to start Remote Desktop to run TS applications.

Running TS application is very transparent: the client has to open an .rdp file which starts automatically the required application **on the same desktop**. The only difference would be the visual appearance of a window (for example on my Windows 7, TS applications from Windows 2008 do not have Windows Aero style). So if you put a shortcut to the MYOB .rdp file in start menu, it will be enough.

Note: when starting TS application for the first time, domain username/password credentials will be asked. If they are remembered, starting a TS application the next time will be as easy as starting an application installed locally.